# Supplementary properties/settings for JavaScript:window.print() to enable Backgrounds by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, colors, background

I would like tot give my *`Print this Page`* button a special magical property sothat it automatically enabled the by default unset property (see picture) namely to Do Print the Backgrounds of div colors and bg images etc.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.print()"><? echo __('Print'); ?></a>
```

Clues, ideas, code, answers or suggestions as answers are all tremmendously welcome and I a will appreciate any hints at all for this dream to come true. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done, unfortunately. This is disabled across all browsers by default (unless a user changes it in *their* settings).

Comment: fortunately i would say :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible . You cannot change the browser settings , if that would be possible people could hack in very easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below

```
<style>
@media print {
    *{ 
        -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important; //for chrome
        Safari color-adjust: exact !important; // For Firefox 
     }
}
</style>
```