# how to set print settings with javascript?

Tags: javascript, printing

I want to set all print settings like: portrait / landscape, no. of copies, no. of pages, page size and quality using JavaScript

Is there any way to achieve this?

If yes please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 5):

this can not be done with JS. the only thing you can do is a print css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

this will be used only when you print.

PS: And im happy it can't be done. Imagine every website could mess with your print params.

Comment: Unless you are a corporation.

Comment: then you are using IE6 with some active x that makes it possible :P

Answer (score 3):

This question is very similar to [Supplementary properties/settings for JavaScript:window.print() to enable Backgrounds by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373535/supplementary-properties-settings-for-javascriptwindow-print-to-enable-backgro)

The best you can do in javascript is window.print() but this only opens the dialog and you cant put in any parameters.

Answer (score 0):

For IE: [scriptX from Meadroid](http://www.meadroid.com/scriptx/)